# Positioning the legend of a pie in highCharts with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

The data for the series is dynamic.If the number of elements in the series are more than three then the alignment will look like this[image]

Which is expected from it but when the elements in the series are less than 3 then the alignment is [image]. The code for this positioning is below`legend: {
                    symbolHeight: '0',
                    x: -90,
                    y: 45,
                    itemMarginTop: 5,
                    itemMarginBottom: 5,
                    itemStyle: {
                        font: 'Lato, Arial, sans-serif',
                        fontSize: '9px'
                    },
                    align: 'right',
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                    labelFormatter: function() {
                        var color = APP.Constants.ERROR_MANAGEMENT.COLOR_CODES[ this.options.colorCode ];
                        return '<span style="color: ' + color + ';">' + this.name + ': ' + this.y + '</span>';
                    }
                }`

SO please help me to get a constant position of the legend items without depending on the data coming

Comment: I use your options and in both examples (with single or more series) the legend is in the same position. http://jsfiddle.net/yw6pqbqr/

Comment: Hello sebastian , This is the exact approach which i tried. As you can see the position is not constant in both the cases.Which i want  is the position to be constant no matter how may legend items we get

Comment: But in my demo works properly and I cannot replicate the issue. Could you update my code with yours to introduce problem?

Comment: Please check here my friend. https://jsfiddle.net/hv4bak62/

Comment: The legend position is not fixed..both from left and from top.I want it to be fixed from left( i mean horizontally ).

Comment: Set the static width parameter per legend items. https://jsfiddle.net/zk1bvzro/

Comment: Sebastian i think you have user text-align property for the data with higher elements you have used 'text-align: left' property and because of it the position of the legends is constant in your case. Is there really no other generic way to make it constant position without depending on the data??

Comment: Maybe better is create HTML legend and place that absolutely by CSS? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/N3KAC/1/

Comment: Yeah it could be done way..But is this any fault of highcharts API ?